# What is a proper way to detect the last item in an iteration in QGIS

Tags: python, qgis

I am creating a plugin for Qgis and the method to detect the last iterable item seems too abstract for my knowledge.

```
for f in layer.getFeatures():
    if != last item:
        file.write ('some formatted text},')
    else:
        file.write ('some formatted text}')
```

On the Last, iteration, I don't want to put the coma but rather just a closing curly bracket.

Answer (score 0):

A more pythonic way to do this is use the `join` method to glue your data together from a list. So

```
file.write(','.join([f['attr_name'] for f in layer.getFeatures()])
```

will write a list of the attribute called `attr_name` separated by commas.

```
file.write(','.join(f"My attrib is {[f['attr_name'] for f in layer.getFeatures()]}")
```

will do the same but uses a formatted string for each attribute.